# Conditionally format dynamic dashboard page with font sizes, borders, cell size, and alignment?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Conditionally format dynamic dashboard page with font sizes, borders, cell size, and alignment? 0 Replies 0 Upvotes
I've created a view only dashboard page that gets automatically populated from another tab and trying to figure out how to spruce it up.

Conditional formatting leaves a lot to be desired and doesn't offer some formatting options that would be nice for this use case.

Do I have any options here? I've added some more context to my sheet and it should be editable to everyone:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyQl6sexw1-i2fGytTAaa9fWog4OLzeGqqLjrdjEMLs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your "Dashboard" sheet, the amount of rows per day will vary I'm assuming, so when for example row 10 is the Title row, maybe when the sheet gets updated, row 10 becomes a   Assignee row, which has a different format. So there is no easy way to keep these formats on the right row as data updates. I would perhaps something like designing the dashboard differently, maybe adding columns for the dates and fixed row headers, then an endless amount of equally formatted rows.